# log4j jdbcappender pass username to database table

Tags: java, log4j

I have log4j jdbcappender configuration as follows:

```
 <appender name="jdbcAppender" class="bean.CustomJdbcAppender">
        <param name="jndiDataSource" value="myDS"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="INSERT INTO log_table (level, loc, msg) VALUES ( '%p','%C;%L', '%m' )"/>
        </layout>
```

How can I pass username to the database table from log4j?

Thanks

Comment: Personally I'd use an MDC or NDC, otherwise you need to include it in your message. But what do you mean by "user name"? User of what?

Comment: username is the user logged into my application. I am getting username to plain custom NTLM authentication without third party filters like Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context), like [this example](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/).

So, somewhere you need to map the username, e.g.:

```java
MDC.put("username", username);
```

In your log4j configuration, you can use it like this:

```xml
<param name="ConversionPattern"
      value="INSERT INTO log_table (level, loc, msg, username) VALUES ( '%p','%C;%L', '%m', '%X{username}' )"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a question, I already have a servlet which I am using for getting logged in user to my application using NTLM authentication. So is it possible to `MDC.put("username", username);` in my existing servlet to map the username? So that I could avoid servlet like AuthenticationFilter as mentioned in the blog?

Comment: I have added MDC.put("username", uname); in my login.jsp and I could see the value getting dprinted in console when I run my application. However username is null at times, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: 1) At which place do you perform authentication (any specific servlet or filter)? 2) Put the username in the MDC at that place - or start debugging from here.

Comment: When I print the value of `MDC.get("username")` I always gets in the following order `INFO (myManagedBean;60) MDC null`  `INFO (myManagedBean;60) MDC Pon`  `INFO (myManagedBean;60) MDC null`  `INFO (myManagedBean;60) MDC Pon` i.e alternatively I get null values.

Comment: I am putting the value in the managedbean constructor of landing page after login.

Comment: So, are you sure it is related to Log4J or to your application? I'm afraid, I don't know enough about your application.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, it was nothing to do with Log4J. I have put `MDC .put("username", uname);` in the correct place and that resolved the issue. Many thanks.