# How to use custom columns with jdbcappender?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, log4j2

I am able to log the application trace in a database table using jdbcappender. Now I would like to extend the table (add new columns) to include some contextual information, such as user, method name, parameters and so on.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673036/log4j-jdbcappender-pass-username-to-database-table) is a log4j solution where Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) is used to add additional information to the log entry with additional information. In log4j2 the successor to MDC is a [ThreadContext](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html).

This solution works for me, but since this is an application which can have many concurrent users, is it thread safe? Or in other words, is 1 ThreadContext active pro user session?

I am running this application on Apache TomEE.